# Lumen simple route request doesn't work

Tags: laravel, lumen

I installed Lumen on my web server, but I have problems with routes

```
// http://12.345.678.910/
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return "This works";
});
```

But in this second case he cant find directory

```
// http://12.345.678.910/api
$app->get('/api', function() use ($app) {
    return "This dont work";
});
```

In second case I am getting standard 404 error.

```
The requested URL /api was not found on this server.
```

I use Apache, Ubuntu, PHP 5.5 and Lumen

Comment: Have you enabled the Apache url rewrite module?

Comment: does `/index.php/api` work? If so, then your URL rewriting isn't working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like your URL rewriting isn't working. If you add `index.php` to the URL right before the `/api` does it work?

For example, `yourdomain.com/api` would become `yourdomain.com/index.php/api` and if the second URL works, then rewriting isn't working.

If your rewriting isn't working, but you have the `.htaccess` file in your `public` directory, then you probably need to allow overrides in your Apache configuration. Here is an example virtual host configuration for Lumen on Ubuntu.

I've marked the lines you need to change. Change the first and third to point to the `public` directory in your website's directory. Then change the second line to the domain name you're using with your website.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/lumen/public"      # Change this line
    ServerName yourdomain.com                 # Change this line
    <Directory "/var/www/lumen/public">       # Change this line
        AllowOverride All    # This line enables .htaccess files
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to restart Apache for these settings to take effect.

#### A Better Way

Enabling the `.htaccess` file should work, but using `.htaccess` slows down your site some. The best solution is to put the contents of the `.htaccess` file in your virtual host, and then disable `.htaccess` files.

The example virtual host configuration for that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/lumen/public"  # Change this line
    ServerName yourdomain.com             # Change this line

    <Directory "/var/www/lumen/public">   # Change this line
        # Ignore the .htaccess file in this directory
        AllowOverride None

        # Make pretty URLs
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
                Options -MultiViews
            </IfModule>

            RewriteEngine On

            # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
            RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

            # Handle Front Controller...
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once again, you'll need to restart Apache for these settings to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

In the root of your application, create a `.htaccess` file if its not already there. Then paste the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I assuming that you are using `apache` server and have `mod_rewrite` turned on.

Read basic configuration section in Lumen [documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#basic-configuration).

If you are unsure how to turn on `mod_rewrite`, this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) might help you.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the .htaccess file under `public` folder is missing.
Check this: https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/public/.htaccess